# Implement Simulated Thread#sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, simulation

## Background

I am designing my software so that I can easily perform unit tests. I have an `IClock` interface which, among other methods, has 
`IClock#wait(TimeUnit timeUnit, long duration)`. This method will halt the current thread for *timeUnit duration* (i.e. 1 second).

There are two implementations of the `IClock` interface:

- `SimulatedClock`: has methods to manually increase the time stored in the clock
- `RealClock`: time increases automatically by referencing `System.currentTimeMillis()`

This is the default method for `IClock#wait(...)`:

```
/**
     * Locks current thread for specified time
     *
     * @param timeUnit
     * @param dt
     */
    default void wait(TimeUnit timeUnit, long dt)
    {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        scheduleIn(timeUnit, dt, lock::unlock);
        lock.lock();
    }
```

## Problem

The current way I want simulated unit tests to work is

1. Start threads
2. *Wait until all threads are either done or in a blocked state (I am assuming if they are blocked, they have called `IClock#wait(...)`)*
3. If all threads are finished, finish. Else, increase `SimulatedClock` time by one millisecond.

However, what is really happening is:

1. Start threads
2. Start increasing time even though threads have not called `IClock#wait()` for the first time.

**So, what I need to do is to be able to determine when all threads are done or blocked**. Although this can be done with `Thread#getState()`, I would rather employ a solution which is more elegant and works with `ForkJoinPool`.

## Full Code

[GitHub](https://github.com/ezAuton/ezAuton/tree/feature-seperate/Core)

### SimulatedClock

```
package com.team2502.ezauton.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SimulatedClock implements IClock
{

    private long time = 0;

    private List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();

    public SimulatedClock() {}

    public void init()
    {
        init(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void init(long time)
    {
        setTime(time);
    }

    /**
     * Add time in milliseconds
     *
     * @param dt millisecond increase
     * @return The new time
     */
    public long addTime(long dt)
    {
        setTime(getTime() + dt);
        return getTime();
    }

    /**
     * Adds time with units
     *
     * @param timeUnit
     * @param value
     */
    public void addTime(TimeUnit timeUnit, long value)
    {
        addTime(timeUnit.toMillis(value));
    }

    /**
     * Add one millisecond and returns new value
     *
     * @return The new time
     */
    public long incAndGet()
    {
        return addTime(1);
    }

    /**
     * Increment a certain amount of times
     *
     * @param times
     */
    public void incTimes(long times, long dt)
    {
        long init = getTime();
        long totalDt = times * dt;
        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            if(!jobs.isEmpty())
            {
                addTime(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        setTime(init + totalDt);
    }

    /**
     * Increment a certain amount of times
     *
     * @param times
     * @return
     */
    public void incTimes(long times)
    {
        incTimes(times, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getTime()
    {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time)
    {
        jobs.removeIf(job -> {
            if(job.getMillis() < time)
            {
                job.getRunnable().run();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleAt(long millis, Runnable runnable)
    {
        if(millis < getTime())
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You are scheduling a task for before the current time!");
        }
        jobs.add(new Job(millis, runnable));
    }

    private static class Job
    {
        private final long millis;
        private final Runnable runnable;

        public Job(long millis, Runnable runnable)
        {
            this.millis = millis;
            this.runnable = runnable;
        }

        public long getMillis()
        {
            return millis;
        }

        public Runnable getRunnable()
        {
            return runnable;
        }
    }
}
```

### Simulation

```
package com.team2502.ezauton.command;

import com.team2502.ezauton.utils.SimulatedClock;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Simulation
{

    private final SimulatedClock simulatedClock;
    private List<IAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Simulation()
    {
        simulatedClock = new SimulatedClock();
    }

    public SimulatedClock getSimulatedClock()
    {
        return simulatedClock;
    }

    public Simulation add(IAction action)
    {
        actions.add(action);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param timeoutMillis Max millis
     */
    public void run(long timeoutMillis)
    {
        simulatedClock.init();

        actions.forEach(action -> new ThreadBuilder(action, simulatedClock).buildAndRun());

        simulatedClock.incTimes(timeoutMillis);

        // Need to wait until all threads are finished
        if(!ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Simulator did not finish in a second.");
        }

    }

    public void run(TimeUnit timeUnit, long value)
    {
        run(timeUnit.toMillis(value));
    }
}
```

### Example Unit Test

```
@Test
public void testSimpleAction()
{
    AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Simulation simulation = new Simulation();
    simulation.add(new DealyedAction((TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5) -> atomicBoolean.set(true)));
    simulation.run(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 100);
    Assert.assertTrue(atomicBoolean.get());
}
```

Comment: But why you can't use Thread.sleep? Why you need to simulate it here?

Comment: I want the unit tests to be run as fast as possible. For example, I might want to simulate an action which would actually run for 100 seconds in the real world but could be run in a matter of milliseconds when simulated.

Comment: Why do you create Threads manually and manage the scheduling yourself, rather than using the existing `ScheduledExecutor` infrastructure? And to be clear, you want to make sure that the `Runnable`s under test are finished by `n` milliseconds, right?

Comment: Your use of ReentrantLock() in IClock#wait(...) makes absolutely no sense because each calling thread would get a separate instance of the lock.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the various threads are not getting going in time, before `simulatedClock.incTimes()` is called.

Often with a multi-threaded test, there is some kind of 'rendezvous' at the start - to allow all of the threads to check-in once they are safely up and running.  If you know how many threads there are going to be up front, a `CountDownLatch` makes this easy.

E.g. in `Simulation.run()`:

```
    simulatedClock.init(new CountDownLatch(actions.size()));
```

Which keeps a reference to the `CountDownLatch` for later.

When each thread arrives in `SimulatedClock.scheduleAt()`, it can count the latch down by one:

```
@Override
public void scheduleAt(long millis, Runnable runnable)
{
    if(millis < getTime())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You are scheduling a task for before the current time!");
    }
    jobs.add(new Job(millis, runnable));

    countDownLatch.countDown();
}
```

Then `incTimes()` can wait for all the threads to show up:

```
public void incTimes(long times, long dt)
{
    countDownLatch.await();

    long init = getTime();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but you shouldn't create `Thread`s manually and use the existing concurrency framework.

You can just do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicBoolean bool = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = executorService.schedule(() -> bool.set(true), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        boolean b = future.get(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
    }
    assertTrue(b);
}
```

You can also integrate it into your framework if your `scheduleAt` returns the `Future`.

```
interface Clock {
    Future<?> scheduleAt(long millis, Runnable r);
}

class SchedulerService implements Clock {
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public Future<?> scheduleAt(long millis, Runnable r) {
        Instant scheduleTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        if (scheduleTime.isBefore(now)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You are scheduling a task for before the current time!");
        }
        long delay = scheduleTime.minus(now).toEpochMilli();
        return executorService.schedule(r, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: "
"I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but you shouldn't create Threads manually and use the existing concurrency framework.": this is your opinion presented as fact

Comment: @gpasch It is a quote from Brian Goetz, so it's not my opinion alone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should rename *IClock.wait* to *IClock.sleep* to avoid confusion.

For  *RealClock*, this method may delegate to *Thread.sleep()*

For *SimulatedClock*, this method may be implemented along the following lines:

```
void sleep(TimeUnit timeUnit, long dt) {
    final Object mon = new Object();
    scheduleIn(timeUnit, dt, 
        () -> {
            synchronized(mon) {
               mon.notify();
            }
        });
    synchronized(mon) {
        try {
            mon.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

You may modify this to throw *InterruptedException*.

Comment: Object#wait() should always be called in a loop

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Linux, there is a sneaky way. There's a utility (annoying I can't remember its name, and a Google search isn't finding it for me at the moment) that you can use to run your program for you. Any time your program calls something that results in a sleep, it intercepts that and replaces it with a zero-length sleep. I think it also starts lying about the time of day too to compensate.

As this works for anything compiled with glibc, which includes the JRE, it would work with any Java application too.

Apologies once again for not being able to provide a useful link - I'll keep hunting my bookmarks / searching because it sounds such a useful thing and I'm annoyed with myself for not being to remember what it was called.

EDIT

The purpose of doing this that you don't have to have two separate implementations in your own program. The standard library calls for sleeping are intercepted at a lower layer than your program.

This is not the one I was thinking of, but it's along the same lines: [timeskew](https://github.com/vi/timeskew). This appears to tinker with `nanosleep()`, `clock_gettime()`, and `select()` plus some related functions, so there's a good chance that it will cover off the basics.